# How to interpret thermometer sensor reading values?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

how to interpret values for this sensor:

[image]

The value is 12 bits, so values can be as much as much as 4096. The temperature range is -40 to +125 Celcius. What is the meaning of -9.05 LSB/degreeC?

[user manual](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL354_355.pdf) p33

Comment: lsb is the lsbit of the raw data, or you can think of the 12 bit data as counts or in units of lsbits up to 4096 counts each count has the weight of one of the lsbits.  think of it is counts/degreeC.  so if you want degreec do your dimensional analysis  you want degreeC/counts times counts counts cancels out and you are left with degreesC   so you have the raw data in counts and you have 1/-9.05 degreesC/count so at some point you are going to be dividing the counts by -9.05 to cancel out counts and leave units of degreesC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 25°C the 12-bit extended register should hold 1852 (all numbers are base 10).

For each degree C above 25°C the reading should decrease by an average of 9.05. So for 45°C the reading should be 1852-9.05*20 = 1671. Similarly it will increase by 9.05 average for each degree C below 25°C

These are nominal numbers and specified as being uncalibrated, so they will vary from unit to unit.

The nominal (uncalibrated) temperature T in °C for a given count x is:

T \$ \approx \frac {1852-x}{9.05} + 25 \$